# Show specific JSON values in a nunjuck template

Tags: json, nunjucks, eleventy

Trying filter values from a JSON-file and showing in an nunjuck-template.
This is the JSON-file:

```
{"rows":
 [
   {"value":
    {
     "name":"'s Gravenwezel",
     "zip":"2970"
    }
   },
   {
    "value":
    {
     "name":"'s Herenelderen",
     "zip":"3700"
    }
   },
   ...
  }
 ]
}
```

When adding **{{ cities }}** in the nunjuck-template, it shows the whole JSON-file, but how can i show only the specific values **name** and **zip**?

Trying this:

```
{{ cities.rows }}

{{ cities.rows[0] }}

{{ cities.rows[0].value[0].name }}
```

...

```
Also trying with a for-loop:
{% for city in cities %}
  {{ city[0] }}
{% endfor %}
```

And a lot of other combinations. Nothing works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd modify the for loop to use cities.rows. Then you can address keys via value.X. So for example:

```
{% for city in cities.rows %}
 {{ city.value.name }} and {{ city.value.zip }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Raymond Camden thanks a lot for your answer. That's works perfect!!!!